# How can a viewController know when an app did just finish launching?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I've made a simple single view program in xcode 4.3.1. I'd like the view to do different things depending on if it is being loaded the first time the application starts vs when it is being resumed.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this?

The appDelegate has no reference to my viewController so I'm not sure I can pass a variable from my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

How does the AppDelegate communicate with the ViewController when the ViewController does not seem to be instantiated anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] to determine if you just started. It is only called once when you launch. You can combine that with setting some flags and 
[applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application] to determine if you launched or are simply returning to the foreground.

Comment: I realize this, but how can I access those flags from my viewController? When you create a single view application there is no reference to the ViewController they make for you in the AppDelegate...

Comment: Set a static boolean or something when the application launches in your [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] method. Check the state of that in [applicationWillEnterForeground:].

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still confused. I've uploaded a picture. As you can see there is no reference to ViewController in the AppDelegate. If I create a static variable in the app delegate how will the ViewController viewDidLoad method be able to read that variable?

Comment: Use standard C practice of setting a GLOBAL variable. If you declare it properly it can be seen by ANY class, anywhere in your program.

Comment: Thanks! I declared a global in the appDelegate then imported AppDelegate.h into the viewController file.

Comment: Global variables are generally considered bad programming practice, in any language. An alternative if you want to avoid them is to use notifications as in the other answer. Its more elegant and object orientated.

Comment: To itgiawa: If you are going to use a global variable. Put the header declaration in some OTHER header file that you use to ONLY declare globals and #import that, NOT the AppDelegate.h.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotificationCenter to know when the application enters the foreground, and then you can register individual VCs to care about the event. For example:

```
- (void)loadView {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

The VC registers during loadView (or any other method). Then when the app enters the foreground, the method

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground;
```

is called. Just remember to unregister in dealloc or viewDidUnload.

```
- (void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[super dealloc];
}
```